# Detect user installed browser extensions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Errors reported by users are often the result of some browser extension.  I would like to populate a hidden field on our "Report a Bug" form with the list of extensions the user has installed to help us quickly troubleshoot.  Can this be done?

Thanks in advance for your help.

> **Duplicate Question?**
>
> *This question was closed as a duplicate from something opened 12 years ago and last active 4 years ago.  Browsers and JavaScript change
> frequently.  Is the answer to the duplicate question still accurate?*

Comment: *Is the answer to the duplicate question still accurate?* Maybe, maybe not. But, one could post an updated answer to the linked duplicate, is not?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't really care about age. We close questions as duplicate to keep all the answers in one place. We don't want people to search through heaps of posts to find up-to-date data. If there is a better answer, it should be posted to the linked post. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: AdrianMole + Ivar ... Fair enough.  Thanks.